# the task `rubber:' does not exist

Tags: amazon-ec2, rubber

I am following Ryan Bates [rubber and amazon ec2 episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2?view=asciicast) and when running the following command I get an error:

```
$ cap rubber: create_staging
triggering load callbacks
* 2014-08-26 00:53:42 executing `rubber:init'
the task `rubber:' does not exist
```

I was able to run `rubber vulcanize` before without a problem. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake, but I am answering here anyways.

I have an extra space in the command `cap rubber: create_staging` it should be `cap rubber:create_staging`

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. I did direct insatallation using

```
gem install rubber
```

but then I added gem to Gemfile and it was started to run

```
gem 'rubber'
```